# Animating "background-position" in an Interval using random values of a predefined array

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, background-position

I want to **randomly animate the body's background-position in an interval**.
There are a few predefined background-position values (x, y) stored in an array.

Here's the script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xyz = new Array();
    xyz[1] = "backgroundPosition: '0% 0%'";
    xyz[2] = "backgroundPosition: '53% 34%'";
    var item = xyz[Math.floor(Math.random()*xyz.length)];

    var move = setInterval(function(){
        $('body').animate({item}, 2000);
    }, 7000);
});
```

Can someone tell me where the issue is? Any code optimizations?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item should be redefined every time. And also, `Math.floor(Math.random()*xyz.length)` can be 0 so I added 1+ to your calculation since you start at key 1 on xyz.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var xyz = new Array();
        xyz[1] = {backgroundPosition: '0% 0%'};
        xyz[2] = {backgroundPosition: '53% 34%'};     

        var move = setInterval(function(){
            var item = xyz[1+Math.floor(Math.random()*(xyz.length-1))];
            $('body').animate(item, 2000);
        }, 7000);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, though this throws following error (in FF 15.0.1):
"SyntaxError: invalid object initializer
$('body').animate({item}, 2000);"

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting item each time. Modified code. In your code item is being set only once. Moving that line inside setInterval will change item set every time.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var xyz = new Array();
        xyz[1] = {"backgroundPosition": '0% 0%'};
        xyz[2] = {"backgroundPosition": '53% 34%'};     

        var move = setInterval(function(){
            var item = xyz[Math.floor(Math.random()*xyz.length)];
            $('body').animate(item, 2000);
        }, 7000);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, though this throws following error (in FF 15.0.1): "SyntaxError: invalid object initializer $('body').animate({item}, 2000);"

Comment: @James Cazzetta You are not passing correct  value I made the change. have a look.